# Why synchronizedList not working properly

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, synchronize

I have written the following code using synchronizedList():

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package collectionsdemo;

import java.util.*;

class ThreadTest implements Runnable
{
    Thread t;
    private int var;

    public ThreadTest(int var)
    {
        t = new Thread(this);
        this.var = var;
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println(var);
    }
}

public class CollectionsDemo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<ThreadTest> synlist = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        synlist.add(new ThreadTest(1));
        synlist.add(new ThreadTest(2));
        synlist.add(new ThreadTest(3));
        synlist.add(new ThreadTest(4));
        synlist.add(new ThreadTest(5));
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            synlist.get(i).t.join();
        }
        //System.out.println("Sunchronized list is :"+list);
    }

}
```

Now, still i am getting output not in the correct order. They are coming in different order everytime. What to do now? How to use synchronizedList() method correctly?

Comment: What order are you expecting? Why?

Comment: Go and read the `Collections.synchronizedList` spec again. You will discover that it has nothing to do with the order of starting the threads (but only that provides thread-safe operations)

Comment: The whole point of threads is *parallel execution*. Why would you expect them to run in any particular order?

Comment: Another thing, what about join() method? Will the above code of mine guarantee that after all the threads dies main thread will start execution  again? This is also very important for me to know?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding threadtest object in synchronizedList, so all the objects are getting added in list in they order you inserted because it is a list and since it is synchronizedList it provides you additional threadsafe feature.

When you execute your program it is printing numbers in different order because that number is getting prointed by treadtest class which is a thread, and you can't control execution order of threads this way.

But to make sure the added objects are in natural order you can add getVar() method in ThreadTest class and loop through your list and print var value you can see it's in same order;

```
        class ThreadTest implements Runnable
        {
            Thread t;
            private int var;

            public ThreadTest(int var)
            {
                t = new Thread(this);
                this.var = var;
                t.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println(var);
            }

            public int getVar(){
                return var;
            }
}


            public class CollectionsDemo {
                 /**
                 * @param args the command line arguments
                 */
                public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
                    List<ThreadTest> synlist = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
                    synlist.add(new ThreadTest(1));
                    synlist.add(new ThreadTest(2));
                    synlist.add(new ThreadTest(3));
                    synlist.add(new ThreadTest(4));
                    synlist.add(new ThreadTest(5));
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        synlist.get(i).t.join();
                    }

                    for(ThreadTest test :synlist){
                        System.out.println(test.getVar());
                    }
            //        System.out.println("Sunchronized list is :"+synlist);
                }

            }
```